# Is inclusion map epic?

Tags: general-topology

$i:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the inclusion arrow. If there are continuous $f, g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow Y$, $Y$ is a $T_2$ space, and $f\circ i = g\circ i$, then $f=g$

In category theory language, $i$ is epic in **$Top_2$**, the category of $T_2$ spaces.

Is $i$ still epic in $Top_1$, the category of $T_1$ spaces?

In general, if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an arrow in $Top_2$, and $f(X)$ is dense in $Y$, then $f$ is epic. It's claimed that $f$ is not necessarily epic in $Top_1$, but I can't find a counterexample.

This is the extension from question 2.2.8 of Harold Simmons's *An Introduction to Category Theory*. The solution manual does not solve this extension.

Comment: What does "epic" mean, here?

Comment: @Danu epimorphism

Answer (score 0):

If you want a counterexample, the more continuous maps to a fixed $Y$ exist, the situation is better. And there is the coarsest $T_1$ topology on every set. So let $Y$ be $ℝ$ with the cofinite topology and let $f$ be the identity. Now observe that any finite-to-one map $g:ℝ \to (ℝ, $ cofinite$)$ is continuous.